# want to do calculation on DataFrame's Colums in python and than the adding that result to the same datafram as a new colum

Tags: python

[here are the colums in dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b90QO.png)

wants to perform these calculations

```
active energy per mint = global_active_power*1000/60 - sub_metering_1 - sub_metering_2 - sub_metering_3
```

here is code which I wrote but not getting how to do that.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
training_set = pd.read_csv('household_power_consumption.txt', delimiter = ';', low_memory=False)
consumed_energy_every_minute = training_set.Global_active_power * (100/60) - training_set.Sub_metering_1 - training_set.Sub_metering_2 - training_set.Sub_metering_2
```

and than want to add that value column to the the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will do the job:

```
import pandas as pd
f=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
f['k']=f.a*1000/60 - f.b - f.c
```

The original `f` looks like

```
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

And the updated `f` looks like

```
    a   b   c   k
0   1   4   7   5.666667
1   2   5   8   20.333333
2   3   6   9   35.000000
```